# How to enable hibernation on my netbook?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make hibernate/sleep work on laptops where default setup isn't working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2235/how-to-make-hibernate-sleep-work-on-laptops-where-default-setup-isnt-working)

When I choose to hibernate, my netbook goes to a black page and hibernate does not work. What steps can I take to allow my netbook to hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

The official Ubuntu wiki provides information on how to [triage and debug](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspendHibernateResume#Debugging%20Hibernate) suspend failures. There also is a helpful page on [understanding suspend](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnderstandingSuspend) which mentions some debugging methods.