# Toshiba Satellite U400 does not resume from suspend

Tags: suspend, toshiba-satellite

I have upgraded from ubuntu 10.4 to 10.10 and the issue seems to be that when I close my lid I have set the computer to suspend. When I open my lid I get a black screen with the login but keyboard is not working. I am using a Toshiba Satellite U400, and didn't manage to find something suspicious at my log files. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sysadmin related. I voted [belongs-on-SU], but you may want to check out http://askubuntu.com/ also/instead.

Comment: @jscott You are totally right, is it possible someone to migrate it to askubuntu.com?

Comment: @Chris it is likely this question will get migrated to SU, as there is no migration path from SF to askubuntu. If you want and answer there, you will need to repost your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a Toshiba U-400, [and Maco's answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2235/how-to-make-hibernate-sleep-work-on-laptops-where-default-setup-isnt-working/2242#2242) is similar to Pitto's.

In our case, it's the bluetooth module that prevents the laptop from resuming from suspend.  You need to add this line to /etc/default/acpi-support.

```
MODULES="toshiba_bluetooth bluetooth btusb"
```

That should get you running again.  Despite this change, perhaps 1 in every 25 or so suspends (not resumes) will fail for me.  When it fails, it cycles the CPU and fanspeed up pretty high.  **Do not trust this laptop to suspend correctly**.  It suspends very quickly, so when you close the lid, keep your eye on it for the 3 or 4 seconds it takes to complete (the amber light under the trackpad should go off).

If it doesn't, you're looking at a fire hazard!

Answer (score 3):

As was mentioned this was repaired with a kernel upgrade to >= 2.6.36

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and yet I couldn't test a solution I've found...
As soon as I get back home I'll post back results.

"You can try to put the name of your proprietary module (nvidia or
fglrx (for ATI) are most likely) in the quotes in MODULE="" in the
/etc/default/acpi-support file and reboot.

sudo nano /etc/default/acpi-support

This'll make that module unload before suspend and reload after
suspend. It sometimes works, but it's also possible that you have just
plain buggy drivers somewhere and need to file a kernel bug.

EDIT: It's also very possible that you've just plain found a bug. If
you think that's the case, please file it: ubuntu-bug linux"

Comment: it looks like an upgrade of kernel to 2.6.36 from here http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.36-maverick/ resolved the suspend issues for me.

Comment: @Chris Can you make your comment an answer if that fixed the problem?

Comment: Upgrading my kernel might have fixed the issue (I didn't test), but I had so many issues with VirtualBox after upgrading that I went back to stock and with my ACPI-support modification, suspend/resume works okay.