# removed ati proprietary driver, tried to hibernate, destroyed ubuntu installation. help?

Tags: grub2, ati, hibernate, proprietary

I totally ruined my Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop x64 installation today. I've never been able to hibernate or suspend (not with my laptop, server or htpc), not even through this [guide](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Ubuntu_Suspend_/_Wake). So I read a post here on askubuntu.com that said that the proprietary drivers may be in the way for it to work.

Therefore I removed my ATI-drivers, rebooted, then tried to hibernate the system. I got some error about "blk_something_something didn't work, resubmitting[1](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Ubuntu_Suspend_/_Wake)". So I turned off the computer and then tried booting up. I see the ubuntu splash but after that I'm greeted with this screen:

[image: My computer screen after booted up]

The upper dot is the mouse pointer since I can move it with the mouse (I have ubuntu set to login automatically). I don't know how this happened.

What can I do to fix this? I'm getting seriously irritated over how buggy ubuntu is, why doesn't even suspend/hibernate work (remember that I have 3 different systems where it fails)?

So what is the next step? I want to get into cli mode and reinstall the driver but since I'm relatively new to ubuntu I don't know how to get into a terminal without logging in first. And if I press shift during boot I can't get into grub either and try something from there.

Please come with all suggestions you can think of!

Thank you very much!

edit: Can I use ubuntu on a usb to insert the driver I need - if that is the problem?

Comment: Regarding the suspend/hibernate issues, do you have any USB 3.0 ports? See [Suspend fails and I know the module causing it. What can I do?](http://askubuntu.com/q/25540/6969) if you do.

Comment: Only on the htpc, the server and laptop only have 2.0 ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1 to get into console mode, login in using your normal credentials. Then you get a CLI where you can do what you want (Probably `sudo apt-get install fglrx`). 
You can switch back to the graphical desktop with Ctrl-Alt-F7.

Comment: When I press ctrl+alt+f7 I get a repeating error message stating:
[ ~number increasing~] [drm:radeon_ib_schedule *ERROR* radeon: couldn't schedule IB(~number counting from zero up to 15~)

Comment: [ ~number increasing~] [drm:radeon_cs_ioct Faild to schedule IB !

Comment: I put it into several comments to make it easier to read since the linebreaks got removed when I added the comment. I keep getting this error message and cannot make an input. What next?

Comment: (Update) I can make inputs even though the message keep appearing. I'll let you know if I make it work.

Comment: @ error messages: could be this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati/+bug/586243

Comment: Yup, seems like the same bug. After I installed fglrx and rebooted from cli it worked! I'm back into the desktop environment! Thank you very much for all the help!

Comment: no problem, you're welcome :-)