# Ubuntu Hibernation is not working properly in 11.04

Tags: hibernate

When I do hibernate on Ubuntu 11.04, it doesn't remembers the last known working state; The last working state is completely lost after hibernate.

How can I make sure hibernate works!

uname -a

```
 2.6.38-11-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 29 19:05:14 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make hibernate/sleep work on laptops where default setup isn't working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2235/how-to-make-hibernate-sleep-work-on-laptops-where-default-setup-isnt-working)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!